# msdeploy returning unauthorized when using the admin account and correct username / password

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I am trying to use msdeploy on my web servers using the /MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE method and it is continually saying i am not an admin and not authorized but i am using the administrator account and am using the correct password. Internally if i try the webdeploy.axd it works but that method is not an option for me due to port concerns.

Here is one of the command strings i use

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" ..\mysolution.sln /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=%CONFIG% /verbosity:m /fileLogger /maxcpucount:4 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=%CONFIG% /p:MSDeployServiceURL=http://%SERVER% /p:UserName=Administrator /p:Password=%PWORD%
```

Here is another one that is returning the same issue:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver,computername=%MACHINE%,username=Administrator,password=%PASSWORD% -dest:webserver 2<&1
```

This happened after i updated msdeploy to version 3.5 and moved my development environment to vs2013. Unfortunately i can not downgrade either of these. Aside from those changes nothing else has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always asking the question has reveled the answer.

If this group policy key is set to '*Guest Only*' msdeploy will **NOT** work. 
I switched it back to '*Classic*' and now it works properly.

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\ Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Network Access: Sharing and security model for local accounts.
```

I know i said nothing changed but my admin seemed to have forgotten about that change. He has since been feed to the sharks with laser beams on their foreheads.